# Is this in-text citation correctly punctuated?

Tags: punctuation, citation

I wonder if the following punctuation I made in my literary translation for an in-text citation is correct in conventional English. Or should I omit the period after parentheses? Or should I omit the period ending the quotation?

> “Both speak of deporting a king who obtains his crown and throne and marries a beautiful princess.” (Abjadian, 1987:147).

Note: In the source language, it was not connected to any sentence before or after it. So I translated it as it was.

Comment: What does the 1987 mean? Is that the year? I personally have never seen a date in an in-text citation.

Comment: Depends on where you're going to publish, and what citation style they use. You might want to check the bibliographic guidelines of the journal(s) you're submitting to. Once you've identified the appropriate style, there are a number of [online tools](http://www.citationmachine.net) to help you format your citation properly.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the citation, that apparent year-colon-page formation is alien to every citational style I know, but I would have to know the style you are aiming for (such as APA, MLA, CMS, whatever) in order to correct it for you. The choice among such styles is normally up to your professor or editor, and not up to you. But I can tell you that you should omit the period just before the closing quotation marks. That is not a point (pun intended) on which styles differ.

Comment: Some journals may be running page numbers across the year so that the reference turns out to be of the form year:page. This is a known practice.

Comment: In fact I am just translating a text into English. I know it's meant to be a journal article but I don't know which style is it aimed for and I don't have access to original writer to ask. I didn't know if citation styles will differ on the above question. However, I will follow you last point i.e. omitting period just before the closing quotation mark.